# Store output of grep to a variable with delimiter

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file sample.txt with following text

```
abcde
cde
abcdefg
efga
abgd
efghji
```

I want to search for the strings containing `bc` with `grep bc sample.txt` and get the output to a variable with a delimiter (say `##`). How can I do it? Output should look something like this.

```
abcde##abcdefg##
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [awk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWK) with somthing like this:

```
OUT=$(awk '/bc/ {printf "%s##",$0};' file)
```

This will save the output in the variable `$OUT`.

```
$ awk '/bc/ {printf "%s##",$0};' file
```

It works by searching for occurrences of `/bc/` and then adding the suffix `##`, Notice the use of `printf` instead of `print`, this is because `print` always adds and line break and with `printf %s##` you avoid that, `$0` will return the full line.

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple solution:

```
grep bc | tr '\n' '#' | sed 's/#/##/g'
```

Simple substitute newline with '#' using tr, then substitute '#' with two '#' using sed.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep bc sample.txt | tr "\n" "#" | sed "s/#/##/g"
```

translate new lines into #, translate 1 # into 2 ##

probably there is a better way but that works fine . . .